# How to get specific dynamic DOM elements in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, swiper.js

I have an SSR site setup that uses a carousel library (swiper js).
The issue I have is the library generates the required HTML with its relevant CSS classes, after page load...which is fine.
Now, I need to get the dynamically generated element created by the library, with the "active" class. Along with that, I also need to grab the 3 siblings to its left, and 3 three siblings to its right (recursively if they exist).

The way I went about this, is to use a `useEffect`, in which I grab the active element out of the DOM, and then check each time to see if the left or right elements have a sibling, up to 3 times each.

```js
useEffect(() => {   
    let activeSlide = document.querySelector(".swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active");
    if(activeSlide.previousSibling){
        let current = activeSlide.previousSibling;
        current.classList.add("out-left");
        if(current.previousSibling){current = current.previousSibling; current.classList.add("out-left");}
        if(current.previousSibling){current = current.previousSibling; current.classList.add("out-left");}
        if(current.previousSibling){current = current.previousSibling; current.classList.add("out-left");}
```

Although this works, it feels really dirty and it's like I am not grasping how to properly manipulate the DOM, when it is dynamically generated after page load.
Are there any better approaches?

I have tried using refs, but because the slides I want do not exist in the code, I can't get my head around it.
Any better methods please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use the Swiper [events and properties](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties) directly. You can look at the `realIndex`, `activeIndex`, and `slides` property to determine where the current slide is in relation to siblings.

Example below should get you started:

```
const handleInit = (e) => {
  console.info(e, e.realIndex, e.slides.length);
};

const handleSlideChange = (e) => {
  console.info(e, e.realIndex, e.slides.length);
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper className="mySwiper" onInit={handleInit} onSlideChange={handleSlideChange}>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I will give this a go, the handleInit seems to be the way to go. Thanks very much.